# Socket timeout exception using MongoDb C# driver

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an API method that when hit, queries a MongoDb collection for all entries associated with a given id (normally 2 or 3 results.) The same query is made elsewhere in my project with no errors, but when it is made via this API method, I get frequent Socket Exceptions as below:

### Stack trace:

```
   [IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.]
    System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size):241
    MongoDB.Bson.IO.ByteBufferFactory.LoadFrom(Stream stream):37
    MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings readerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions):174
    MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.GetFirstBatch(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider):204
    MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.Execute(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider):0
    HireSpaceVenue.Data.BookingsData.GetBookingLines(IMongoQuery query) in c:\a\src\HireSpaceVenue.Data\BookingsData.cs:474
    HireSpaceVenue.Data.BookingsData.HireSpaceVenue.Data.Interfaces.IBookingsData.GetBookingLinesByBookingId(String bookingId) in c:\a\src\HireSpaceVenue.Data\BookingsData.cs:147
    HireSpaceVenueWeb.Controllers.EnquiriesController.GetUpdate(String bookingId) in c:\a\src\HireSpaceVenueWeb\Controllers\EnquiriesController.cs:130

[SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond]
    System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size):172
```

### Code:

```
    //build query
    ...

    // initialise the connection
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(_mongoConnectionString);
    MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
    MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase(_databaseName);

    // get the collection
   MongoCollection<LazyBsonDocument> bookinglines =
   database.GetCollection<LazyBsonDocument>("bookinglines");

   // query the collection
   MongoCursor<LazyBsonDocument> mongoCursor = bookinglines.Find(query);

   // do something with the retrieved data
   ...
```

This code is contained in a method that is called from a number of places, but I only seem to get the timing out issue when it is called from the API method.

Any explanations/possible causes?

Comment: This usually happens when the server isn't where you specified it is. Are you using a replica set? Are you calling server.Disconnect() anywhere in your code?

Comment: We are using a replica set and no, I don't call server.Disconnect() anywhere...

Comment: in your replSet config, (rs.config() from the shell), are you referencing ip addresses or hostnames and, are you able to ping those ip addresses/hostnames from the client box?